# ¿Por que este trigger no inserta nada en ninguna de las dos tablas?

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin, mariadb

La sintaxis no me marca ningun **error** lo que significa que tengo mal la logica, el problema es que soy nuevo en `phpmyadmin` y no se muy bien si coloque los if correctamente

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER VALIDADOR BEFORE INSERT ON validaciones FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    SET @FOLIO=(SELECT new.folio FROM validaciones);
    SET @NOMBRE= (SELECT new.nombre FROM validaciones);
    SET @APELLIDO=(SELECT new.apellido FROM validaciones);
    SET @COLONIA=(SELECT new.colonia FROM validaciones);
    SET @CALLE=(SELECT new.calle FROM validaciones);
    SET @NUM=(SELECT new.num FROM validaciones);
    SET @CP=(SELECT new.cp FROM validaciones);
    SET @CIUDAD=(SELECT new.ciudad FROM validaciones);
    SET @FORMA_DE_PAGO=(SELECT new.forma_pago FROM validaciones);
    SET @factura= (SELECT new.nombre_fact from validaciones);
    SET @TIPO= (SELECT new.type from validaciones);
    SET @DATOS=(SELECT new.data from validaciones);
    SET @usuario= (SELECT new.nombreusu from validaciones);
    SET @FECHA =(SELECT new.fecha FROM validaciones);

    SET @accion = "";

    IF @FOLIO = 0 THEN BEGIN SET @accion = "El error es el folio";
    END;
    END IF;
    IF @NOMBRE='E' THEN BEGIN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre";
    END;
    END IF;
    IF @APELLIDO = 'E' THEN BEGIN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre";
    END;
    END IF;
    IF @NUM = 0 THEN BEGIN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre";
    END;
    END IF;
    IF @CP = 0 THEN BEGIN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre";
    END;
    END IF;
    IF @CIUDAD = 'E' THEN BEGIN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre";
    END;
    END IF;
    IF @FORMA_DE_PAGO ='E' THEN BEGIN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre";
    END;
    END IF;
    IF @accion <> "" THEN BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO log (fecha_val,error,nombre_fact,nombre) VALUES (@FECHA,@accion,@factura,@usuario);
    END;
    END IF;
    IF @accion = "" THEN BEGIN 
    SET @accion = "no hay error"; 
    INSERT INTO log (fecha_val,error,nombre_fact,nombre) VALUES (@FECHA,@accion,@factura,@usuario);
    INSERT INTO validaciones (folio, nombre,apellido,colonia,calle,num,cp,ciudad,forma_pago,nombre_fact,type,data,nombreusu,fecha) 
    VALUES (@FOLIO,@NOMBRE,@APELLIDO,@COLONIA,@CALLE,@NUM,@CP,@CIUDAD,@FORMA_DE_PAGO,@factura,@TIPO,@DATOS,@usuario,@FECHA);
    END;
    END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ¿No te esta dando ningun error al ejecutarlo? Proba hacer que se active y fijarte cual es el resultado. Aparte de eso me parece que tu codigo esta algo engorroso, el begin y end no hacen falta en un if de una sola linea y todos los selects del principio se pueden hacer en una sola consulta

Comment: Propongo las siguientes modificaciones al trigger: https://pastebin.com/iX75nfy8
posiblemente te este dando error porque los selects del principio retornan mas de una row, ademas de que no hace falta llamar a la tabla Validaciones para obtener esos datos ya que los accedes por la variable new( que no pertenece a ninguna tabla ). Ademas de deshacerse del doble insert que no hace falta ya que el registro va a insertarse en la tabla, el hacer ese insert al final generaria un llamado recursivo al trigger( lo cual tambien es un error de mysql )

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, Sacha tu código me funciono a la perfección :D

Comment: Ahora escribo la respuesta asi la das como valida, encantado de ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui hay varios problemas, los ire listando:

1. Los selects del principio dan error, ya que deberian ser consultas de 1 row y estos regresan n rows, ademas de no necesitar datos en la tabla.
2. Las variables no son necesarias ya que los datos estan en el new.
3. Por legibilidad de codigo esos ifs se pueden reducir a una sola linea, sin begin ni end.
4. Hace dos veces la misma pregunta por @accion = "" y @accion <> "", lo cual se puede solucionar con un solo IF y su correspondiente ELSE.
5. Ultimo y mas importante de todo, el trigger llama a un insert en la tabla a la que pertenece, lo cual crea un llamado recursivo resultando en error.

   El codigo con las respectivas correcciones aplicadas que propongo se ve asi:

   ```
   SET @accion = "";

   IF new.folio = 0 THEN SET @accion = "El error es el folio"; END IF;
   IF new.nombre ='E' THEN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre"; END IF;
   IF new.apellido = 'E' THEN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre"; END IF;
   IF new.num = 0 THEN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre"; END IF;
   IF new.cp = 0 THEN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre"; END IF;
   IF new.ciudad = 'E' THEN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre"; END IF;
   IF new.forma_de_pago ='E' THEN SET @accion = "El error es el nombre"; END IF;

   IF @accion = "" THEN
       SET @accion = "no hay error";
   END IF;

   INSERT INTO log (fecha_val,error,nombre_fact,nombre)
   VALUES (new.fecha,@accion,new.nombre_fact,new.nombreusu);
   ```